# Magento Product pages incomplete after adding image(s) to the product

Tags: magento

I imported the products using a csv list and now I am adding the images to each product one by one in the backend. But after adding the image, the product page in the frontend only shows the image and everything else like add to cart, description, configurable options and so on are missing, the source code simply ends after the image box. Did anyone else ever notice a similar behavior?

Comment: This means there is an error somewhere preventing the execution of the remaining code. Often there is no file where the file should be, or no permission to read.

Comment: I found out that html production stucks on the following function in a templates phtml file:
`<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image', $_image->getFile())->resize(600,600);?>`
Is anything wrong with this?

Comment: This almost definitely means the image file is not where it belongs or the the image is not set as base image, did you forget to check the radio button in the image upload? In addition try to clear the cache and update the indizes.

Comment: thats the weird thing: everything is setup correctly in the backend, caches clearde and indexes rebuilt. Also the image is displaying, the functions above this one are working fine with the image, ie some lines above the previously mentioned function I found this function returning the right value:
`$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(600,600)`
so the only difference is the getFile function

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood, the only difference is not the get file function, the 1. function i posted is also for the gallery images not just the base image, base image is showing correctly, but below it, in the galleries section, the mentioned function is the point where the html code stops, since this functions needs $_image, this function above it could also lead to the misbehavior: 
`getGalleryImages()`

Comment: SOLUTION: had to change $product to $_product two times in this row, but I am still curious why.